# Why do external stylesheets appear as inlined when viewing source?

Tags: css, browser, stylesheet

Lately I've noticed a strange behaviour in my browsers, when developing a website or doing some debugging.

When I click on View Source to check the site's HTML source code, the external stylesheets that I coded as links appear now inlined, that is, in its entirety.

What appears is something like this:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css" style="display:none">
/*a bunch of CSS styles here, lines and more lines of CSS*/
</style>
```

...instead of the typical:

```
<link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It's happening with Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE... with any browser I use.

Do you know guys what could be going on?

Comment: Can you post the exact code in your code, and the exact output as copied from a browser?

Comment: Guys, it happens to be only when I use my iPhone as a modem... and I really don't know why? Any clues? Is there a way to avoid it? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens to be only when I use my iPhone as a modem... no idea why.

Comment: For the record, hitting F5 to refresh the source code screen will give you a correctly tabbed and linked HTML source...